# Cannot understand what "error: initializer element is not constant" means

Tags: c, kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a small kernel module designed solely for accessing a particular key using the kernel's key retention service. Since I couldn't find a simple function to return a key's contents given its ID, I had to resort to `request_key` as outlined in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/keys.txt).

This line is what gives the error:

```
struct key *my_key = request_key(&key_type_user, "test key", NULL);
```

I'm referencing the proper key type and I still get this error. The function in [security/keys/request_key.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/security/keys/request_key.c) that my code *should* be calling is declared:

```
 struct key *request_key(struct key_type *type,
                         const char *description,
                         const char *callout_info)
```

I don't see anything there about `*type` need to be a constant. I've read that the error message might have to do with false advertising on the part of C as to what makes something "constant", but I can't see how that could relate to the above function. Any help?

Comment: Function call itself is OK. If errorneous line is outer of any function body, that is it defines a global variable, then its initializer should be compile-time constant. This is required by C99 standard. If given line is part of function body, please also post function's code preceding it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to show us the context of your declaration, but from the error you get I'd guess that it is in file scope, declaring a global. Statically allocated objects like that are initialized at compile time, therefore you can't use function calls and other run-time constructs to initialize it.

Comment: I'll post the rest when I can. For now, though, the given is global in scope. But I think the problem, given what I've read in other questions mentioning the error, might have to do with `key_type_user`, a variable defined in [security/keys/user_defined.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/security/keys/user_defined.c#L27), not being declared as a constant.

Comment: No, then it is not `key_type_user`. You are not supposed to have a function call in file scope. This is only allowed inside functions.

Answer (score 0):

If that line is in a declaration section, it has the syntax of an initializer and that may be the compiler's complaint.  Move any declarations which immediately follow it to be above it.  Or split it:

```
struct key *my_key;
my_key = request_key(&key_type_user, "test key", NULL);
```

Comment: For automatic variables, such dynamic initialization is allowed.